# Javascript, require var

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, var

```
 helper.js
```

I usually program in Ruby. I want to get this info:

```
 var shopInfo =
  {
    "shopName": "The Coffee Connection",
    "address": "123 Lakeside Way",
    "phone": "16503600708",
    "prices": 
      {
        "Cafe Latte": 4.75,
        "Flat White": 4.75,
        "Cappucino": 3.85,
        "Single Espresso": 2.05,
        "Double Espresso": 3.75,
        "Americano": 3.75,
        "Cortado": 4.55,
        "Tea": 3.65,
        "Choc Mudcake": 6.40,
        "Choc Mousse": 8.20,
        "Affogato": 14.80,
        "Tiramisu": 11.40,
        "Blueberry Muffin": 4.05,
        "Chocolate Chip Muffin": 4.05,
        "Muffin Of The Day": 4.55
      }
    }
  }
```

I want this in another file in the folder, because I want things to look neat

```
  main.js
```

I've tried this:

```
  var helper = require('./helper');
```

I simply want main.js to know what shopInfo is

Comment: So where is the problem? Please write what's not working and where you're stuck. I can't see a question. You have to be clear in what you're looking for. Then someone can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about a server side node.js program, you can put it in another module file and then export it by assigning to `modules.exports`.

**In helper.js:**

```
 var localShopInfo = {
     "shopName": "The Coffee Connection",
     "address": "123 Lakeside Way",
     "phone": "16503600708",
     "prices": {
         "Cafe Latte": 4.75,
         "Flat White": 4.75,
         "Cappucino": 3.85,
         "Single Espresso": 2.05,
         "Double Espresso": 3.75,
         "Americano": 3.75,
         "Cortado": 4.55,
         "Tea": 3.65,
         "Choc Mudcake": 6.40,
         "Choc Mousse": 8.20,
         "Affogato": 14.80,
         "Tiramisu": 11.40,
         "Blueberry Muffin": 4.05,
         "Chocolate Chip Muffin": 4.05,
         "Muffin Of The Day": 4.55
     }
 };

// assign to module.exports to make it available to other modules
module.exports = localShopInfo;
```

**Then, in main.js:**

```
var shopInfo = require('./helper');
```

You are now free to use `shopInfo` anywhere in main.js.

---

The `require()` loader returns the value of `module.exports` in the module that it loaded.  You then assign that to whatever variable in your current module that you want it to be called.

---

Note: you had an extra closing brace in your `shopInfo` declaration too.

Comment: This answer would be better if you emphasized the need for the **module.exports** part.  I often forget that too.

Comment: @user949300 - two more references added to `module.exports`.